# How do I get Xcode 15.1 to check Swift backward compatibility for iOS 15 in Swift packages?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have recently run into an ugly situation as we did not check our builds against iOS 15 for a while. Our builds ran without any issues on iOS 16 and iOS 17, but on iOS 15 we got:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: DYLD 4 Symbol missing
Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI28BorderedProminentButtonStyleVAA09PrimitiveeF0AAMc
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/53FB853D-69A1-4EDF-A118-A5C56839968D/myApp.app/myApp
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI

Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x0000000101d04be8 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                            0x0000000101cde498 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104 (terminate_with_reason.c:102)
2   dyld                            0x0000000101d0958c abort_with_payload + 16 (terminate_with_reason.c:124)
3   dyld                            0x0000000101cedba4 dyld4::halt(char const*) + 328 (DyldProcessConfig.cpp:2004)
4   dyld                            0x0000000101cc7a00 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 3520 (dyldMain.cpp:0)
5   dyld                            0x0000000101cdb6fc start + 488 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

The error is totally misleading and does not help at all in finding the root of the problem, which was an incompatible swift package.
After filing a DTS ticket with Apple (with no response) and some rather laborious digging, we found that apparently swift packages do not receive the same level of compatibility checking during compilation as in regular projects and we were able to compile and link code that is NOT backward compatible - which causes this crash when the app is started on iOS 15.

Our package is configured like this:

```
platforms: [
        .macOS(.v11),
        .iOS(.v14)
    ],
```

Apparently .iOS14 is the latest supported enum?

Yet code like:

```
if let parallelCommand = command as? any ParallelCommand {
```

or

```
if let current = subject as? CurrentValueSubject<Output,Failure> {
```

did not produce any compiler error or warning (which it apparently does in a regular project).
So be aware there might be issues with Swift packages and backward compatibility.

In case we have missed anything re. how to set up a swift package to properly check for iOS15 compatibility during compilation, I'd be greatful for feedback or advice!

Comment: Can you clarify your question. The error you posted appears to be about the use of the `borderedProminent` SwiftUI button style but the code in your question is completely unrelated to the error.

Comment: @HangarRash The error is what we got, because the swift package apparently linked into nirvana. It was the removal of these runtime casts, the code posted, which are only supported starting iOS16, that fixed the dyld issue above.

Comment: Have you tried building the package on an iOS 15.0 emulator?

Comment: @PierreJanineh How do you build a swift package on an emulator? Or do mean run the app in an iOS15 emulator? In which case It crashes the same way as on a real device.

Comment: I meant, build (Command + B), after choosing the right emulator with iOS 15

Comment: @PierreJanineh Sure - that is implied to run the code on an emulator...

Comment: [Build your targets and run unit tests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-standalone-swift-package-with-xcode#Build-your-targets-and-run-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0):

**Please read Apple's Documentation:** [Build your targets and run unit tests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-standalone-swift-package-with-xcode#Build-your-targets-and-run-unit-tests)

### In your Package:

- specifying `platforms` with `.iOS(.v14)` alone doesn't show a compiler error when it's added to a project with lower minimum iOS version.

> ***Compiler errors are shown when you build/run your project***.

- You can try building (just building, cause there's nothing to run as it's a package not an app) your project on iOS simulators. ***Notice*** that you won't be able to find lower simulator versions than the one declared in `platforms`.

> Ex: if `platforms: [.iOS(.v17)]` then you wouldn't be able to find simulators lower than `iOS 17.0`.

- Use the `@available()` attribute to indicate that a particular class, struct, function, or other declaration is only available in certain versions of a platform.

### For example

```swift
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
func iOSSpecificFunction() {
    // Function implementation
}
```

### Usage in your project:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    iOSSpecificFunction()
} else {
    // Fallback for older iOS versions
}
```

### In your App Project:

- Only if you implement code that's actually not supported by that minimum version, shall the compiler error appear in your Xcode. The compiler won't complain if all your package code is supported by your project's minimum version.